# Installing Octave Documentation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: documentation, octave

I'd like to have on-disk documentation, as there are many times when I must be off the net.  I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Octave 4.0.0.  When I click the Documentation tab I get "The info file /usr/share/info/octave.info or compressed versions do not exist" and that is well and truly the case.  When I run

```
$ sudo apt install octave-doc
```

it runs normally but Octave still can't find it (even after re-launching).

When I run

```
$ find /usr -name "octave.info*"
```

or

```
$ find /opt -name "octave.info*"
```

I can't find it anywhere.

It's now time for me to ask for help.  Is it possible to get the documentation installed, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1 covers what you need, but I did not see any reference to how to install it. So, here is how to install `Octave.info`.

Start a linux terminal session
Type the following command: `sudo apt-get install octave-info`

When the command completes, start `Octave` in the usual way, and when you click the Documentation tab, you will see all the reference documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to `apt-cache show octave-doc`:

> This package provides the following documentation in PDF format: a 
>   reference card in a4, letter and legal formats, a document on the C++ 
>   classes used by Octave, as well as the main octave documentation which
>   is  also included in info format in the octave-info package.

For `.info` documentation and online help, you need the `octave-info` package:

> This package provides the following documentation in info format: a 
>   document on the C++ classes used by Octave, as well as the main octave
>   documentation which is needed for the 'help -i foo' command within
>   Octave.